# TypeScript Date VS Moment VS Object not typesafe

Tags: json, date, typescript, fullcalendar

I know... this is an old and annoying question. And there are several questions in one. But they belong together since this is a problem from practice.

I dont find an acceptable answere to this problem and need some more explanation:

State:

In TypeScript a class with a Date property.

```
export class A 
{
  date: Date;
}
```

From DB-Rest comes a JSON `{"date": "123456789"}` pased with `response.json()` to the object.

```
...
let a:A = new A();
...
a = response.json();
```

So far as expected.

And the creepy behaivour for which I dont find a good and practical workflow:

```
a.date.toISOString() //fail: .toISOString not function (or any other Date functions)
```

OK - its just a empty Object. And no Date prototype...need to create new Date()...

Problem here: Where is the "type saftey" from TypeScript here?

also possible in FullCalendar Event Handling e.g.

```
a.date = fullCalendarEventDate; //works
(aka. Moment which dont have a constructor at all?? Does it extend Date?)
```

Bottom line I ended up here for performance reasons:

let d:Date = new Date();
...
d.setTime(a.date); // failed: Date is no number

Finally I have this:

```
let dateTmp:Date = new Date(a["date"]);
dateTmp.toISOString();
```

This cant be the most performant and practical soulution for this issue!

So you all know this problem and you are probably a better Web-Dev than me.

**Please tell me your tricks to handel these points:**

- JSON DateSrtings to fullCalender and back to JSON in TypeScript.
- How to achive true type safety in TypeScript. 
  (e.g. a VO.constructor with Array and Date creation maybe?)
- Why I cant use these Moment Objects as any other class? (new Moment())

Comment: fullCalendar just uses moment under the hood (it extends it in one or two cases (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/Moment/) which may or may not apply to you. MomentJS does not "extend" Date. Effectively you can think of it a (superior) replacement for Date. If necessary you can pass a Date object to momentJS to create a new moment. Moment does have a constructor but not like you showed. Read the docs.

Comment: The "trick" for passing dates into fullCalendar is just to use moment objects, since that's what fullCalendar uses. Although again if you read the fullCalendar docs it will often accept Date objects or strings in certain formats (basically anything that the moment constructor accepts). And lastly I don't know typescript but I'd guess in that class you're just creating a property which you want to be a date, but that is not the same thing as actually instantiating an object to put in it. It feels like mostly your question can be answered by reading the relevant documentation instead of guessing

Comment: Thanks @ADyson This already explains a lot. Typescript is another case. Guess lot of my problems coming from mixing JS libs and TS language.